# How should an imported module have access to global constants (VERBOSE=True), etc.?

Tags: python, module, namespaces, python-import

I'm having difficulties to see how should constants be defined in a modular code (using main.py + 2 modules), here in this example the `VERBOSE` and `SAMPLINGRATE` constants.

#### main.py

```
VERBOSE = True
SAMPLINGRATE = 44100

import numpy
from module1 import Class1
from module2 import Class2

items1 = []
items2 = []

for i in range(100):
    items1.append(Class1(i))
    items2.append(Class2(i))
```

#### module1.py

```
import numpy

class Class1: 
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
        ...

    def dosomething(self):
        ...
        if VERBOSE:
            print "We did this and this..."
```

#### module2.py

```
import numpy

class Class2: 
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
        ...
        self.blah = SAMPLINGRATE * i

        if VERBOSE:
            print "We did this and this..."
```

**Question: How and where should the constants `VERBOSE` and `SAMPLINGRATE` be defined?**

Note:

- **I cannot pass all these constants as argument** when creating instances of `Class1`, because if so, I would have to do this ugly thing in `main.py`:

  ```
  for i in range(100):
      ...Class1(i, verbose=VERBOSE, samplingrate=SAMPLINGRATE, <lotsofconstantshere>))...
  ```
- I use a modular design because I want `module1.py` to be used **for other projects** than `main.py`. So if I import `module1.py` in another project `projectB.py`, I would like to have a default value for `VERBOSE` to be `False`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no truly global namespace in python. You need to have a common module everyone imports. Its best if the common module has few side effects (e.g., importing another module that could create circular dependencies). `main.py` is a particularly poor container because its the top level script and isn't a module at all. Other importers would get a different `main` as a module.

So you could create **config.py**

```
VERBOSE = True
SAMPLINGRATE = 44100
```

and all of your modules simply do

```
from config import *
```

Comment: This could work, but I'd like to be able to import `module1.py` from another project that doesn't have a `config.py`. How to do this? i.e. `module1.py` contains its own default values for VERBOSE and SAMPLINGRATE that can be overriden by a config.py if any?

Comment: Try to use environment variables for these things